# Why should weights in neural networks be initialized according to the number of neurons?

Tags: neural-network

Conventionally, if the activation function is tanh the initial weights should be uniformly sampled from [image]

While if the activation function is sigmoid the initial weights should be uniformly sample from [image]

Why should weights be sampled from these ranges?

Comment: This could possibly be a question more suited to Theoretical Computer Science SE. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/